# Alarm Manager broadcasts unexpectedly

Tags: android, alarmmanager, unix-timestamp, milliseconds

I have a application which should fire up an alarm at a specified time stored in the database.
The time is stored like (HH:mm) format, 24-hour format.

Here is the code.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String temp = h+":"+m;
Date date = sdf.parse(temp);
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)_c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(_c, AlarmBroadcastReciever.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(_c, requestCode, intent, 0);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+  date.getTime(), alarmIntent);
```

_c: context variable
h is the hour (24-hour format) and m is the minutes.

I wanted to fire the alarm at 4:30 am but it got fired immediately at 03:09:35 AM.

How to schedule alarms only one time at that specific time (no-repeating)?

PS: I am tending towards using alarms because the application needs repeating alarms all at dynamic times based on database queries.

Comment: It’s partly a time zone issue. Which time zone are you in? As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int h = 4;
    int m = 30;
    LocalTime alarmTime = LocalTime.of(h, m);
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    long alarmTimeMillis = LocalDate.now(zone)
            .atTime(alarmTime)
            .atZone(zone)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(alarmTimeMillis);
    System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(alarmTimeMillis));
```

When I ran this today, the output was

```
1522882800000
2018-04-04T23:00:00Z
```

To check whether the millisecond value of 1 522 882 800 000 was correct I converted it to an `Instant`. Instants always print in UTC, so the time printed agrees with 4:30 AM in Asia/Kolkata time zone (offset +05:30). You will probably want to add a check to see if the time is already passed, and if so, add one day so the alarm happens at the specified time tomorrow. `LocalDate` and some of the other classes have a `plusDays` method for that.

If you get your alarm time as a string like `04:30` from the database, parse it like this:

```
    String alarmTimeString = "04:30";
    LocalTime alarmTime = LocalTime.parse(alarmTimeString);
```

The rest is the same.

I am using and recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. Because `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome, and its friends `Date` and `Calendar` are long outdated too. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

### What went wrong in your code?

There are two bugs in your calculation of the alarm time:

1. While your parsing produces a `Date` that prints as for example `Thu Jan 01 04:30:00 IST 1970` and thus looks right, this is deceiving. The 04:30:00 is in your local time zone. When you use `date.getTime()`, you get the number of milliseconds since the epoch, and the epoch is defined in UTC, not in your time zone. For example, I used Asia/Kolkata time zone and got milliseconds of -3 600 000, equal to *minus* 1 hour.
2. `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()` gives the time now. When adding your milliseconds to this time, you specify an alarm time that number of milliseconds from now — in my example an alarm time 1 hour ago.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.