# How to time in milliseconds from pass time string with reference to the current date

Tags: android, datetime

I am trying to pass a string of the form `12:00` into milliseconds based on the current date but I seem unable to get a good understanding of how the `Calendar` and `Date` class work to achieve this.

Now I have this code:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
String alarmPref = preferences.getString(PreferenceUtility.getReminderTimes(context), "12:00");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
Date date = format.parse(alarmPref);
startTime.setTime(date);
```

This unfortunaltely gives me when logged like this:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Time to start:" + futureTime);
Log.d(TAG, "Date: " + date);
```

Gives the following results:

```
07-25 14:45:21.057 8409-8409/com.google.developer.bugmaster D/PreferenceUtility:Time PreferenceUtility: 21:20
07-25 14:45:21.057 8409-8409/com.google.developer.bugmaster D/QuizJobScheduler: Time to start:126000
Date: Thu Jan 01 12:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970
```

As seen the required string is `21:20` ( as expected ) but `Time to start` remains at the value `126000` and hence I keep getting the date to be `Date: Thu Jan 01 12:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970`, which of course is a reference to the `epoch` date and time.

How can I get a reference date and time that refers to the time of `21:20` and for the current date the app is running. Forgive me for my ignorance as I have tried so many literature with no success most likely I am unable to understand them.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alarm Manager broadcasts unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661237/alarm-manager-broadcasts-unexpectedly)

Comment: A link to good examples with reference to my query would be nice

Comment: Didn’t I just provide that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49675035/5772882

Comment: My apologies for not seeing that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
    String time = "21:20";
    String[] splittedTime = time.split(":");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Set the current date and time
    calendar.setTime(new Date());

    // Set the desired hour and minute
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(splittedTime[0]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(splittedTime[1]));

    // Clear seconds and milliseconds
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    // the variable date will get today's date and the desired time
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

I hope you understand my comments in the code

Answer (score 0):

Java's `Date` class does not provide the means to set ONLY the time while using the current calendar day. Android's `Calendar` class does.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
```

This above example requires you to parse the time without a SimpleDateFormat. Splitting the string in half (using the ':') and integer parsing the two strings would give you the values to put in.